# Audio playing errors in silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

Errors are
       **1)The current chunk is too big 
       2)Invalid file format

       3) 3220 3220 An error has occurred****

Code is this :

```
 private void TestPlaybutton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stream stream11 = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            WavManager.SavePcmToWav(_stream2, stream11, _sink.CurrentFormat);
            WaveMediaStreamSource wavMss = new WaveMediaStreamSource(stream11);
            SoundClip.SetSource(wavMss);
            SoundClip.Play();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

and SavePcmToWav function:

```
                      public static Stream SavePcmToWav(Stream rawData, Stream output,       AudioFormat audioFormat)
    {
        if (audioFormat.WaveFormat != WaveFormatType.Pcm)
            throw new ArgumentException("Only PCM coding is supported.");

        BinaryWriter bwOutput = new BinaryWriter(output);

        bwOutput.Write("RIFF".ToCharArray());

        bwOutput.Write((uint)(rawData.Length + 36));
        bwOutput.Write("WAVE".ToCharArray());
        // -- FORMAT chunk
        bwOutput.Write("fmt ".ToCharArray());
        // Length Of FORMAT Chunk (Binary, always 0x10)
        bwOutput.Write((uint)0x10);
        // Always 0x01
        bwOutput.Write((ushort)0x01);
        // Channel Numbers (Always 0x01=Mono, 0x02=Stereo)
        bwOutput.Write((ushort)audioFormat.Channels);
        // Sample Rate (Binary, in Hz)
        bwOutput.Write((uint)audioFormat.SamplesPerSecond);
        // Bytes Per Second
        bwOutput.Write((uint)(audioFormat.BitsPerSample * audioFormat.SamplesPerSecond * audioFormat.Channels / 8));
        // Bytes Per Sample: 1=8 bit Mono, 2=8 bit Stereo or 16 bit Mono, 4=16 bit Stereo
        bwOutput.Write((ushort)(audioFormat.BitsPerSample * audioFormat.Channels / 8));
        // Bits Per Sample
        bwOutput.Write((ushort)audioFormat.BitsPerSample);
        bwOutput.Write("data".ToCharArray());
        bwOutput.Write((uint)rawData.Length);
        long originalRawDataStreamPosition = rawData.Position;
        rawData.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[rawData.Length];
        int read;       
        while ((read = rawData.Read(buffer, 0, 4096)) > 0)
        {
            bwOutput.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        rawData.Seek(originalRawDataStreamPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return output;
    }
```

?????
where is the problem and is there any alternative to play stream  with in silverlight
i am using these classes,
WaveMediaStreamSource, wavparser, waveformatex

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my Problem.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="SoundClip" AutoPlay="True" MediaOpened="SoundClip_MediaOpened_1"  Volume="1" />
```

I just change AutoPlay from False to True and it worked for me.